# MaxBounds and custom asymmetric padding in Mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a Mapbox GL JS app, where over a map I display some widgets. To make sure nothing on the map will be hidden by them I've added some padding using `map.setPadding()`. It's an asymmetric one (left is larger than right in my case). It works as intended for things like `fitBounds` and animation but I also need to set up `maxBounds` of the map so the user won't pan out of the desired viewport. Unfortunately that doesn't work well with custom padding. When I draw the bounds and use `showPadding` I can see that those lines won't align. The problem grows bigger the bigger I make the difference between the paddings.

I was wondering if anybody had similar issues or can lead me to a solution where I can have map clamped to some bounds while still being able to use custom padding like I described above.

Here's an example of the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/1ysrgkcL/45/ Notice how the thick black rectangle doesn't align with the padding lines.

Comment: This question would be easier to answer with a specific example, and code, preferably in a codepen or similar.

Comment: @SteveBennett hmm, I've got this proof read by a colleague and we thought it was enough to understand the issue but maybe an example would also be good. I've updated the question with an example.

Comment: Without code, someone can answer if they happen to already know the answer, like they've seen it before. With code, someone can answer if they know how to debug and diagnose issues, and are willing to.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into same problem earlier and i fix it using:

- **fitBounds** as it add's the amount of padding(in pixels) to the given bounds.
- **requestAnimationFrame**: In its callback i received the getBounds and set it as max bounds(trick)

Updated code snippet:

```
<script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnBhY2h1Y2EiLCJhIjoiY2lxbGNwaXdmMDAweGZxbmg5OGx2YWo5aSJ9.zda7KLJF3TH84UU6OhW16w';

        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
            center: [-73.9774108244587, 40.820698485268366],
            zoom: 11.6
        });

        map.on('load', function () {
            const padding = { left: 300, right: 100, top: 100, bottom: 30 }; //<--- padding

            const bounds = {
                "n": 40.896790957065434,
                "s": 40.76021859203365,
                "e": -73.85756962495667,
                "w": -74.09102645202957
            }
            const maxBounds = [[bounds.w, bounds.s], [bounds.e, bounds.n]];

            //<---- notice here--->
            map.fitBounds(maxBounds, {
                padding, //<--- used here
                linear: true,
                duration: 0
            });

            map.showPadding = true

            //<---- notice here--->
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                const getBoundsFromViewport = map.getBounds();
                map.setMaxBounds(getBoundsFromViewport);
            });

            const boundsRect = [
                [bounds.e, bounds.n],
                [bounds.w, bounds.n],
                [bounds.w, bounds.s],
                [bounds.e, bounds.s],
                [bounds.e, bounds.n]
            ]

            map.on('click', (e) => console.log('##', e.lngLat.toArray()))

            map.addLayer({
                'id': 'bounds',
                'type': 'line',
                'source': {
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': {
                        'type': 'Feature',
                        'geometry': {
                            'type': 'LineString',
                            'coordinates': boundsRect
                        }
                    }
                },
                'paint': {
                    'line-color': '#000000',
                    'line-width': 10
                },
                'layout': {}
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And it will like charm in your case too. Attaching screenshot:
[image]

Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks for reply! Indeed it looks better, but you forgot to call `map.setPadding({left: 300, right: 100, top: 50, bottom: 30})`. In that way the padding can be set globally so everything later (all animations etc) will take that padding into account. Does this mean I have to manage the padding on my own? Because with that line added the experience is still broken.

Comment: No need of ```map.setPadding```. padding option in used in fitBounds method and updated the code snippet again.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. The initial render works indeed better. But what about when after the initialization I do an animation like map.flyTo - I have to pass in the same padding there so it centers it correctly, right? To avoid doing that I thought setting global padding would do the trick.